# Alternative to TEXTJOIN

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, concatenation

Currently working on building an Excel form within Microsoft Teams, but it will eventually need to be downloaded to a user computer to be filled out.  TEXTJOIN works online within Microsoft Teams, but this will be downloaded to Excel 2010 without TEXTJOIN functionality...so I'm hoping to use the CONCATENATE function.  Not sure how it fits into my current formula to get the same result.  Here's the current formula:

=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(D12:D19=Sheet2!C8, IF(C12:C19="High Importance", A12:A19, ""), ""))

Thanks

Comment: Without TEXTJOIN, you will need to concatenate 8 `IF`s or use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to concatenate 8 `IF`s:

```
= MID(IF(AND(D12=Sheet2!C8,C12="High Importance"),", "&A12,"")&
      IF(AND(D13=Sheet2!C8,C13="High Importance"),", "&A13,"")&
      IF(AND(D14=Sheet2!C8,C14="High Importance"),", "&A14,"")&
      IF(AND(D15=Sheet2!C8,C15="High Importance"),", "&A15,"")&
      IF(AND(D16=Sheet2!C8,C16="High Importance"),", "&A16,"")&
      IF(AND(D17=Sheet2!C8,C17="High Importance"),", "&A17,"")&
      IF(AND(D18=Sheet2!C8,C18="High Importance"),", "&A18,"")&
      IF(AND(D19=Sheet2!C8,C19="High Importance"),", "&A19,""),3,999)
```

---

As to vba, see here for a TEXTJOINIFS() UDF:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

You would use the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOINIFS(A12:A19,", ",D12:D19,Sheet2!C8,C12:C19,"High Importance")
```